# wp7 sms sending recieving and sms interceptors

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

Is there any way to send and recieve sms in wp7?

And is there any way smsinterceptors
if not

is there any alternative way to do it?

Any third party tool like that?

Comment: Why would any user knowingly install your *SMS interceptor* app? I don't know about you, but I don't particularly like the idea of someone having the ability to intercept my text messages!

Comment: just to try some alternative for push notification service through sms nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

You can only send a SMS through SmsComposeTask class but like every task you can only show them - actually executing the action is done by the user.
If you want something to do which isn't accessible from the public API you can't do it. In some rare cases you'll find some homebrown apps but only a minority will use them.

If you can't live with this you should choose a different mobile os.